# Is jquery's post() method able to call an asp.net 3.5 webmethod?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

Here's some javascript:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "default.aspx/GetDate",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: {},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(result) {
            alert(result.d);
        }
     });
```

The above method works as I would expect and alerts the string returned from the [WebMethod] called GetDate  in default.aspx

But when I use:

```
$.post(
        "default.aspx/GetDate",
        {},
        function(result) {
            alert(result.d);
        },
        "json"
     );
```

The alert in this success method never fires.

In firebug I can see that the POST has basically worked - it returns 200 OK
But the response in this case is the HTML of the entire default.aspx page rather than the JSON returned when I use the $.ajax() method.

EDIT:
The response and request headers shown in firebug are NOT identical.

With $.ajax()...

```
REQUEST:
Accept  application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-gb,en;q=0.5
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Type    application/json; charset=utf-8
Cookie  (removed)
Host    (removed)
Referer (removed)
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:9.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0.1
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest

RESPONSE:
Cache-Control   private, max-age=0
Content-Length  27
Content-Type    application/json; charset=utf-8
Date    Wed, 11 Jan 2012 12:36:56 GMT
Server  Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By    ASP.NET
```

With $.post()...

```
REQUEST:
Accept  application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-gb,en;q=0.5
Connection  keep-alive
Cookie  (removed)
Host    (removed)
Referer (removed)
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:9.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0.1
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest

RESPONSE:
Cache-Control   private
Content-Length  13815
Content-Type    text/html; charset=utf-8
Date    Wed, 11 Jan 2012 12:36:53 GMT
Server  Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version    2.0.50727
X-Powered-By    ASP.NET
```

Can I use the the $.post() method for this, or do I have to use the $.ajax() method?

Comment: Are you *sure* the request headers are the same? Does the `Content-Type` header not vary?

Comment: Do you definitely need to call a web service?  I've literally just done this using $.get and returning pure HTML (with no headers) and it worked perfectly for my needs.  If this will help then let me know and I'll post some code.

Comment: As many times as I'd read them @lonesomeday, your suspicion is correct - "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" is indeed in the Request Headers from the $.ajax() call.

Comment: @Archer - thanks, but in this instance I _don't_ want to get any html, I want the json!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's normal. When you use `$.post` you cannot set `contentType: 'application/json'` as you do with `$.ajax`. And the server expects this header. So basically you cannot invoke an ASP.NET page method with `$.post`.

Comment: Thanks Darin - this is the answer I was looking for and I think you got in first.

Comment: A bit late after the fact, but wanted to add that this is partly incorrect. `$.post()` **can** be utilized so long as a call to `$.ajaxSetup()` is made prior to configure the default parameters for the async request. I tend to configure these parameters in my master pages or layout views anyway, so the subsequent calls I make are successful using `$.post()`.

Comment: I've only just seen this @lthibodeaux - but thanks for posting. It looks very useful.

Answer (score 3):

I presume this is because your serverside code demands the `Content-Type` header to be set.  The default implementation of `$.post` does not allow this.

If, however, every single time you use AJAX in your application you need this header to be present, you could modify `$.post`:

```
$.post = function (url, data, callback, type) {
    if (jQuery.isFunction(data)) {
        type = type || callback;
        callback = data;
        data = undefined;
    }

    return jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: data,
        success: callback,
        dataType: type
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    });
};
```

With this, *all* `$.post` calls will have `contentType` set. This may be a good idea; it may not...

Comment: Thanks very much for your correct answer and for the workaround - I won't use it, as can see why it could be a problem.  Also thanks for helping me to understand why it was failing.  I couldn't find any mention of this being the case anywhere.  EDIT: Unfortunately I can't mark two posts as answers, and can't even upvote you as my reputation is below 15.  I'll try to remember to come back when it is!

Comment: @mikev2 You could also define a `$.postMVC` function, say, that would do the same but only when you wanted the `contentType` set. That wouldn't affect normal `$.post` calls.

Comment: Now _that_ sounds like a good idea, which I think I will use! Thanks again :)